# Password for Git repository

Tags: git, ssh, hosting, password-protection, ssh-keys

I have a remote repository on hosting and have a SSH-keypair for access. Now I want set a new password special for Git-repository. I want to enter password when I do *git pull* or *pit push*.

Maybe you want know why. Many people have access to hosting. One of them can add his own SSH-key and clone my sources. But it's not good for me. So, I want protect my Git repos by it's own password.

Please, don't suggest create a new user with access only to Git repos. All people have access as a superuser and can see all files in hosting. .ftpaccess can't help.

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0):

> All people have access as a superuser and can see all files in hosting

That means any password you might make for git itself won't prevent superusers to simply tar and copy the bare repos which are hosted on that server.

Adding a password for remote access (git push/pull) won't solve the root cause of the problem (root access by others)